# ¿Como desactivar un ImageButton despuúes del click del usuario, para evitar que el proceso del boton se repita?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion ASP.Net, en la cual tengo ImageButton para la seleccion del tamaño pero cuando el usuario hace más de de un click se guardan registros repetidos.
Como ya habia echo algo similar con un boton normal, lo replique pero en la imagebutton no funciona ya no hace nada.

```
OnClientClick ="this.disabled = true;" UseSubmitBehavior ="false"
```

Ese es el código que funciona en el boton normal pero no en la imagen

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="edimen" Width="240" Height="220" runat="server" OnClick="ed_Click" ImageUrl="img/CAJA.png" />
```

y ese es el de la imagenbutton

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar el evento "OnClick" del ImageButton por:

```
OnClientClick="ed_Click"
```

También puedes hacerso así :

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;"
```